# best way to structure a list in google datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a questionnaire holding a static list of 500 questions.
I wish to present each on of my users those questions, each question only once at the same order for all users, and store their answers.

I was thinking of creating a nested structure where each user will be the parent of his/her answers. whenever a user registers I'll copy all questions' ids from the shared repo and every time I pull a question - I'll   present the user the next unanswered question.

my problems are:
 1. does this sound like a good idea, maybe I need another one?
 2. how will querying for the unanswered questions be efficient and preserve order
 3. will collecting answers from my users be possible with that structure?

(P.S. I don't expect to have more than 30 users)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like a relational schema, than a NoSQL strategy.

Meanwhile, i think that your approach is correct because datastore is a schemaless database, which allows you to worry less about making changes to your underlying data structure as your application evolves.

Datastore provides a powerful query engine that allows you to search for data across multiple properties and sort as needed.

If your questions doesn't have multiple options, i suggest you to relate 1:1 the question with the answer, and link in another tables the answered questions with an uniqueID.

Sounds good for you?